# Why is my render blurry?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, camera, depth-of-field

In the camera settings I didn't set anything regarding Depth of Field but it is still really blurry.

[image: Camera Settings]

I have bump maps included in the sofa, curtains, floor but none is visible because of the blurriness. So I thought maybe it is bc of the distance of the camera but that didn't work as well. Samples are at 1048.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of your render settings?

Comment: @AshutoshBudhdeo ok i added the settings

Comment: I think it's because the resolution is set to 17%. Change that to 100% and render it again.

Comment: @AshutoshBudhdeo yes the render you see is already set at 100. 17% is just for test

Comment: Perhaps you have some compositing nodes like Depth of field, blur, lense distortion or similar

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos no.. i didnt use any of these :( only RGB curves

Comment: In the `Film` tab, what are your settings for `Filter Type` (I mean the dropdown box) and the `Filter Width`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To explain the depth of field, make sure you have the right camera set as active.

Also, the missing detail in your objects could be the result of the denoiser.

Comment: Thank you! i scaled the Feature Strengt on the denooiser from 1 to 0.3. I can see the details finally.

Answer (score 4):

It is because of heavy de-noising.

The cloudy wall and blurred textures but not edges of some objects give it away.

Turn off denoising and render only portion of your frame (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to specify region) with more samples (for example 5000 samples is not a lot for final quality). This way you get a 100% size preview on a area you choose quickly. It should be without any blur. You can then lower samples and turn denoising on and see how far from the "ground truth" you deviated.

By tuning the parameters only on a small region area, you can quickly find what the best setting are, it is different scene from scene. You should pick the most difficult area to render, one where you expect the most artifacts.

Comment: thx for the tip